# Enabling a FTP file tree in Sublime Text/Atom

Tags: ftp, sublimetext2, atom-editor

I have been initially using Sublime Text and have tried with Atom, I have failed to get a FTP file tree like the one used in Dreamweaver (pic below)

[image]

I have FTP working in Sublime but it just brings a FTP hover box and not a fixed file tree. How can this be implemented?

I am also struggling to get auto code indentation working in both programs.

Comment: Please limit your posts to one question each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use:

## [SFTP](https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp)

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 2):

First, please keep in mind that neither Sublime nor Atom are IDEs, they are code editors, and as such will not have all the bells and whistles that an IDE like Dreamweaver will have built in.

At least with Sublime (and as far as I know with Atom as well), the file tree view on the left only displays local files, or those on mapped network drives. That means if you want to see the files on your server, you'll need to map it to a local drive. There are multiple solutions for each operating system. I use [Transmit](https://panic.com/transmit/) on OS X and the `sshfs` utilities on Linux. While the Windows utility [WinSCP](https://winscp.net) does not directly allow for mapping servers to network drives, you can use its [Keep Remote Directory Up to Date](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_keep_up_to_date) task for similar functionality. If you need something more advanced for Windows, just Google [`sshfs windows`](https://www.google.com/#q=sshfs+windows) for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

On Atom you could try [remote-ftp](https://atom.io/packages/remote-ftp). After installing remote-ftp you'll need to create an FTP config file which stores the login credentials. Upon connecting via remote-ftp a remote tree view will be opened to the right of your local tree view.